# Recreate Database from WCF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a code written and WCF file generated to pull data from remote database and rather than pulling the data continuously I would like to create a local database based on the entities available in that WCF file, I created some tables manually by adding fields etc.. but that was time consuming. Is there a way where I can create a SQL database with all the entities and pull all the data from WCF into it rather than doing one by one?

Comment: Seems like you are talking about code first to a new database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: No, I dont even have an entityframework code, I need to create all of that, all what I have is a WCF client file, that I can extract data from but I need to create a database to contain all that data with all those tables, but I dont want to create those tables one by one either in entity framework code first or in the SQL using sql management studio, if that makes sense

Comment: You have entity-framework in your tag, hence why I suggest this approach. That being said, you can still use this approach even if you do not want to use EF. Just use the tooling to accomplish your task.